# Sending ordered broadcast to a specific receiver?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-intent, intentfilter

How can I send an orderedBroadcast to a specific receiver? I am broadcasting the ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON and only want a specific app (Winamp for example) to receive it. I don't want Pandora to steal it. Is there a way to explicitly define who the receiver will be?

```
void sendBroadcast() {

        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
        synchronized (this) {
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, theKeyEvent));
            ctx.sendOrderedBroadcast(i, null);

            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, theKeyEvent));
            ctx.sendOrderedBroadcast(i, null);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the package of the Winamp application, you can use [setPackage](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setPackage%28java.lang.String%29) to restrict Intent resolution to only a specific package.